# Swift - Pass Data from Container to TableViewController using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TabBar with one view of type UIViewController. In this view, I added two containers (one for upcoming deliveries and one for completed deliveries). Each of those two containers is linked to UITableViewController to show tables of relevant orders. To access the containers, I have a segmented control.

I am unable so far with all attempts based on code around and approaches to pass data from the viewcontroller to the tableviewcontrller. Am I missing something?

Here is the code I have in the view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ordersSegementedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var upcomingDeliveriesContainer: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        SwiftLoader.show(title: "Retrieving Orders...", animated: true)
        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        ref.child("ordersSummary").queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue("\(currentUser!.uid)").queryLimitedToLast(15).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            
            if(snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String != "In Progress" || snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String != "Pending" )
            {
                let tempOrderObject = OrderObject()
                //let properDate: UnixTime = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as! Int
                tempOrderObject.dueDateInt = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as? Int
                let properDate: UnixTime = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as! Int
                tempOrderObject.dueDate =  properDate.toDay
                tempOrderObject.referenceNumber = snapshot.value!["orderReference"] as? String
                tempOrderObject.status = snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String
                tempOrderObject.userId = snapshot.value!["userId"] as? String
                tempOrderObject.sender = snapshot.value!["sender"] as? String
                self.ordersObjectsArrray.append(tempOrderObject)
                self.ordersObjectsArrray.sortInPlace({ $0.dueDate > $1.dueDate })
                SwiftLoader.hide()
            }
            
        }){ (error) in
            SwiftLoader.hide()
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }


    
    @IBAction func showComponent(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.upcomingDeliveriesContainer.alpha = 1
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.upcomingDeliveriesContainer.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
    
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        
        if(segue.identifier == "upcomingDeliveriesSegue")
        {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController
            destinationVC.ordersObjectsArrray = self.ordersObjectsArrray
            
        }
    }
```

I then have the following in the UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController:

```
class UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var ordersObjectsArrray:[OrderObject]?
    let orderToPass = OrderObject()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Array Count: \(self.ordersObjectsArrray!.count)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return ordersObjectsArrray!.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Configure the cell...
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewCell
        
        let orderEntry = self.ordersObjectsArrray![indexPath.row]
        cell.dueDateLabel.text = String(orderEntry.dueDate)
        cell.orderNoLabel.text = orderEntry.referenceNumber
        cell.statusLabel.text = orderEntry.status
        cell.senderLabel.text = orderEntry.sender
        
        return cell
    }


    
}
```

the print statement in the UpcomingDeliveriesTableVieController print 0 as count of array items. So far is not being passed.

This is finally the storyboard snapshot:

[image: the embed segue is called: upcomingDeliveriesSegue]

Thank you

Comment: Check if you are reinitialising ordersObjectsArrray in UpcomingDeliveriesTableVieController??

Comment: I am doing this:     var ordersObjectsArrray = [OrderObject]()
@VishalSonawane

Comment: @VishalSonawane sorry didn't get that

Comment: Can you please show me your UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController?? Right from the variable declarations.

Comment: Did you set segue identifier name to "upcomingDeliveriesSegue" in StoryBoard?

Comment: @Igor yes as was mentioned in the question

Comment: @VishalSonawane done updated

Comment: Add in `prepareForSegue` `print("Array Count: \(self.ordersObjectsArrray!.count)")` for ensure, that you pass filled array

Comment: @Igor printed 0 surprisingly

Comment: Just a minor thing not related to your question: In your `showComponent` you're doing the same thing for both, the `if` and the `else` clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue` save only instance of `UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController`, but `ordersObjectsArrray` set only when you get it.

Ex:

in the view controller:

```
var tvc: UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SwiftLoader.show(title: "Retrieving Orders...", animated: true)
    let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    ref.child("ordersSummary").queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue("\(currentUser!.uid)").queryLimitedToLast(15).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if(snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String != "In Progress" || snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String != "Pending" )
        {
            let tempOrderObject = OrderObject()
            //let properDate: UnixTime = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as! Int
            tempOrderObject.dueDateInt = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as? Int
            let properDate: UnixTime = snapshot.value!["dueDate"] as! Int
            tempOrderObject.dueDate =  properDate.toDay
            tempOrderObject.referenceNumber = snapshot.value!["orderReference"] as? String
            tempOrderObject.status = snapshot.value!["orderStatus"] as? String
            tempOrderObject.userId = snapshot.value!["userId"] as? String
            tempOrderObject.sender = snapshot.value!["sender"] as? String
            self.ordersObjectsArrray.append(tempOrderObject)
            self.ordersObjectsArrray.sortInPlace({ $0.dueDate > $1.dueDate })
            SwiftLoader.hide()
        }

    tvc.ordersObjectsArrray = self.ordersObjectsArrray

    }){ (error) in
        SwiftLoader.hide()
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "upcomingDeliveriesSegue")
    {
        tvc = segue.destinationViewController as! UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Not fully understanding what you saying Igor

Comment: `prepareForSegue` executed early, then you get `self.ordersObjectsArrray` in `observeEventType `, understand?

Comment: and in the prepareForSegue above, we create a new variable tvc then what? How do I pass it to next view?

Comment: in viewDidLoad after you get `self.ordersObjectsArrray` pass value, like I add: `tvc.ordersObjectsArrray = self.ordersObjectsArrray`

Comment: `var tvc: UpcomingDeliveriesTableViewController!` create in view controller class

Comment: I understand that but it is not allowing me saying that I have to add self. to this line tvc.ordersObjectsArrray otherwise wont execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120802/discussion-between-igor-and-ksa-coder).